# How to create .ipa file in Xcode8 and how to upload to html link?

Tags: html, ios, xcode8

How can I download ios apps through html link? Can anyone provide a full guide?

Answer (score 0):

You can create a [diawi link](https://www.diawi.com). Which helps users download using link. But here are the conditions

On the self-service, which is here for quick/one-shot app testing, no strings attached, uploaded apps will expire quickly:

- 3 days after the last installation (or after the upload if never
  installed)
- after 10 installations
- 100MB maximum size

Currently, most apps are installed less than 5 times and within 2 days after the upload, and their average size is 20MB, so these new rules should be more than good for most usage.

On the free account, which is more for simple app management, though premium accounts will have the real management features later, uploaded apps will have a bit shorter lifespans too:

- 7 days after the last installation (or after the upload if never
  installed)
- after 25 installations
- 250MB maximum size

You can read more about expiring rules from here: [Diawi link expire rules](https://blog.diawi.com/2016/07/24/new-app-expiration-rules/)

**Note:** App should obey code signing validation. Means only those devices registered in provisioning profiles have capability to install through this link.

**Another site similar to Diawi**: [BetaFamily](http://betafamily.com)

Answer (score 0):

You can create your app ipa file

1. In project navigator Go to Products folder find .app file
2. Show in finder and just copied it
3. Make one folder named Payload and in that copied it .app file
4. Compress that folder and rename it Payload.ipa
5. You can use it your app's .ipa file